# NSDictionary literals, exception on all values method

Tags: objective-c, ios, literals

Given following interface :

```
@interface DetailViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *contentTypeToString;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *contentTypeToContent;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *contentDestcriptors;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *content;
@end
```

And following method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //dumb data

    self.contentTypeToString  =@{
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:ContextTypePlace]   : @"Place",
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:ContextTypeDate]    : @"Date",
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:ContextTypeTime]    : @"Time",
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:ContextTypeWeather] : @"Weather",
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:ContextTypeSeason]  : @"Season",
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:ContextTypeTimeOfDay] : @"Time of Day",
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:ContextTypePlace]   : @"Place",
    };

    self.contentTypeToContent = @{
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:ContextTypePlace]   : @"Dublin",
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:ContextTypeDate]    : @"21.12.2012",
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:ContextTypeTime]    : @"21:32",
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:ContextTypeWeather] : @"Cloudy",
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:ContextTypeSeason]  : @"Winter",
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:ContextTypeTimeOfDay] : @"Evening",
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:ContextTypePerson]  : @"John, Ann",
    };

    self.contentDestcriptors = [self.contentTypeToString allValues];
    self.content = [self.contentTypeToContent allValues];
}
```

I get :

Terminating app due to uncaught exception `NSRangeException`, reason: `*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 6 beyond bounds [0 .. 5]`

Tf I comment out the place where I use the allValues metod, the code works fine. Bug in literals, or my fault?

Comment: If you are using object literal uou can use `@ContextTypePlace` instead of `[NSNumber numberWithInt:ContextTypePlace]`

Comment: Could you post the stack trace when the exception is raised?

Comment: Its actually @(enum-value) not just @enum-value

Answer (score 2):

You specified `ContextTypePlace` twice

That would create a dictionary with 6 items, not 7.

Comment: Still this shouldn't crash `allValues`.

Comment: I think it crashes when **accessing** the array, assuming there are 7 values in the array when there are only 6.

Comment: Yeah, if I dont access its fine.